# How to FIX ERROR can't connect from unity to SQL Server

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server through Unity. However, when I cannot to connect, I get an error

> The type or namespace name 'SqlClient' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I have a SQL Server database, I want input data from unity save to SQL Server and get data from SQL Server to unity.